# singly linked list c - may be used uninitialized in this function (-Wall -Werror)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am getting an `"may be used uninitialized in this function" for: current->next = temp;` I looked it up for hours but could not find any solutions.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head = NULL;

void add_list( int value){
    struct node *temp, *current;
    temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
          head = temp;
          current = temp;
    }
    else{
         current->next = temp;
         current = temp;    
    }  
}

int main(void){
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
           add_list(i);
      }
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `current`? And read the whole message. It is very clear actually.

Comment: I set current right next to *temp.... I dont get "why it would be very clear" cause i will never be in the else{} before I initialize curren = temp in the if{}!

Comment: 'I looked it up for hours but could not find any solutions' - why would you do that?  Is your debugger broken?

Comment: And how does the compiler know that without running the code? Read the message once more: "**may** be used uninitialized ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `head != NULL`, which will be true after you add the first item to the list. Then, your function is:

```
void add_list( int value){
    struct node *temp, *current;
    temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = NULL;

         current->next = temp;  // current is uninitialized
         current = temp;    
}
```

FWIW, you can simplify your function to:

```
void add_list( int value){
    struct node *temp =  malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```